# Можете как можно проще объяснить работу методов Parse и TryParse

Tags: c#

С Convert все понятно, но Parse и TryParse вообще не могу понять.

Comment: Мне до сих пор с Convert не всё понятно, поэтому использую только Parse/TryParse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `Parse` **пробует** получить число из его строкового представления(условно `string value = "123";`), если все ОК,то возвращает число, иначе *исключение*.

Метод `TryParse` **проверяет**: можно ли получить число из строки(пример,условно, тот же). Если можем, то возвращаем `true` и получаем число out-параметром, иначе `false`.

**Ex:**

```
string[] values = { null, "160519", "9432.0", "16,667",
                          "   -322   ", "+4302", "(100);", "01FA" };
      foreach (var value in values)
      {
         int number;

         bool success = int.TryParse(value, out number);
         if (success)
         {
            Console.WriteLine($"Converted '{value}' to {number}.");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine($"Attempted conversion of '{value ?? "<null>"}' failed.");
         }
      }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0